# Reading SPContentMapProvider with CSOM

Tags: 2013, csom, navigation, breadcrumb

Is there a way to get the information from `SPContentMapProvider` through CSOM? I have not been able to find any API endpoint for this in CSOM or REST.

I'm trying to build my own breadcrumb control for team sites and the information rendered by using an `<asp:SiteMapPath>` control with `SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider"` is fairly close to what I try to achive

Eg. You get the full navigation hierarchy, including the site collection, site, list and folder. But I would like to do some additions to it from a provider hosted app endpoint.

Comment: Can you share some additional details like what you are adding via provider hosted app endpoint ? I meant is it going be static content or dynamic content based on the url ?

Comment: For simplicity: Just see it as that I'm trying to read out the same content as the SPContentMapProvider does, for any given page / library / folder @GautamSheth

Comment: doesn't look like it. REST or CSOM. closest there is the the `SP.Navigation` and `SP.NavigationNode`

Comment: @Mike, not it seems to be a lost battle!

Comment: you'd think MSFT would add more objects to surface--guess they are working on other things...